# Getting The Extended Hours close price of 5m, on daily timeframe chart

Tags: pine-script

On Daily timeframe view I tried this:

```
t = tickerid(syminfo.prefix, syminfo.ticker, session.extended)
cc = security(t, "5", close, false)

l = label.new(time, high, text=tostring(cc), xloc=xloc.bar_time)
label.delete(l[1])
```

but it always gives me the daily close price, not the 5m chart, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I realized the expression on security shows the "close" price of the current bar time, which is still the current bar on the daily chart

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything wrong. Extended session information is not available from daily resolutions and up.